Conjugate elements in an extension
I was studying field theory when a question came to my mind.
Given an algebraic extension L/K, two elements of L are said to be conjugate over L/K if there exists a K-automorphism of L mapping one of them into the other. It is known that two conjugate elements of L over L/K have equal minimal polynomial over K, and that the converse is true if L/K is normal. I'm basically looking for a counterexample for the general validity of the converse.
Does it exist an algebraic extension L/K and two elements of L having the same minimal polynomial over K and not conjugate in L/K?

Yes. This is possible.
The first mechanism leading to this conclusion that occurred to me is the following. Consider the case $K=\Bbb{Q}$, $L=\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{2+\sqrt5})$. The number $\alpha=2+\sqrt5\in L$, and therefore also $\beta=4-\alpha=2-\sqrt{5}\in L$. Then $\alpha$ and $\beta$ share the minimal polynomial $m(x)=(x-2)^2-5=x^2-4x-1$ over $\Bbb{Q}$.
But there cannot be an automorphism $\sigma$ of $L$ such that $\sigma(\alpha)=\beta$. For the simple reason that as $L\subseteq\Bbb{R}$ the number  $\beta<0$ has no square root in $L$. Any automorphism of $L$ that maps $\alpha$ to $\beta$ would need to take $\sqrt{\alpha}$ to a square root of $\beta$.
In other words, when $\alpha$ and $\beta$ share the same minimal polynomial there exists an isomorphism $K(\alpha)\to K(\beta)$. As we just saw, it does not necessarily follow that this isomorphism could be extended to an automorphism of $L$.

Somewhat likely to be a duplicate. but I failed to find a good one. I will keep searching in the morning. G'night, all!

morally equivalent:  $\mathbb{Q}(\pm \sqrt{2}) \subset \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2})$, great answer in any case, +1

@orangeskid Your example is simpler. Should have recalled it. Not sure we have an exact duplicate using it. There is this

Very nice answer. Can we build a more universal example? (For sure not with a universal property, but what I mean that it is more "synthetic", maybe by using $K(x,y)$ for something like that.)

@orangeskid I was about to post your answer before I saw your comment.  If I were you I would post it as an answer, as it is a simpler example, so adds something to the existing answer - your decision of course.

@tkf: Thank you for the feedback, did just that.

(from comment to answer) Did find the known example: elements $\pm \sqrt{2}$  in the field $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2})$ only automorphisms $\sqrt[4]{2}\mapsto \pm \sqrt[4]{2}$, fixing the square roots. I think it is quite similar to the example of Jyrki, his quartic field again has two automorphisms that fix both $\pm \sqrt{5}$.
Another example: consider $\pm \sqrt{2} \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{a+b\sqrt{2}})$, with $a+b\sqrt{2}$ properly chosen, say $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2+\sqrt{2}})$.  Now this number field of degree $6$ will have no non-trivial automorphisms.  The only possible one would be
$\sqrt[3]{2+\sqrt{2}}\mapsto \sqrt[3]{2-\sqrt{2}}$ (all cubic roots are real), but the latter is outside the field. Indeed, we do not have
$$a+ b(1+\sqrt{2})^{1/3}+c(2+\sqrt{2})^{2/3}= (2-\sqrt{2})^{1/3}$$
for any $a$, $b$, $c\in \mathbb{Q}$, and in fact, for any $a$, $b$, $c \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$. Why is that: they are (real) radicals of elements ( from $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$) that are incommensurable ( over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ );
It would be interesting to know when we can embed a number field in a larger one with no non-trivial automorphisms.
